# 4d surface graph logistic regression (x,y,z, color)

Tags: r, 3d, logistic-regression, rgl

I'm trying to plot a 4d surface graph of a binomial relationship involving 4 quantitative variables (3 predictor variables and 1 response).
I have forest cover (`cov`), landscape heterogeneity (`het`) and abundance of predators (`abund`) to explain the probability of predation (`pred`).
So I'd like to put on the graph x = `cov`, y = `het`, z = `abund` and a color gradient to represent `pred`. I'd like a graph similar to this:

[image]

My model is:

```
model <- glm(cbind(pred,npred)~ cov + het + abund + abund:cov + cov:het, data=results, family=binomial)
```

My scripts to do the graph:

```
het <- seq(0, 2, 0.05288)
cov <- seq(0, 0.8, 0.021600)
abun <- seq(0, 0.9, 0.024)

gg <- expand.grid(het=het, cov=cov, abund=abund)
gg$pred < -predict(model,newdata=gg, type = "response")
head(gg)

with(gg, plot3d(het, cov, abund, type = "n"))
cols <- heat.colors(20)
cuts <- with(gg, cut(pred, breaks = 20))

with(gg, plot3d(het, cov, abund, type = "n"))
with(gg, surface3d(1:20,1:20, matrix(pred, ncol = 20),
                  color = cols[cuts], back = "fill"))
```

Unfortunately, I think something is wrong and doesn't plot as I imagined.
Can someone help me with the script or suggest something better?

My dataset:

```
het cov abun    pred    npred
1.90164 0.636460117 0.730424235 24  14
2.13681 0.409547496 0.735686442 8   42
2.18218 0.631526938 0.744585387 2   48
2.10223 0.568536934 0.746072471 8   36
2.11588 0.390850929 0.747720518 2   50
2.10288 0.465843118 0.754245798 6   42
2.28891 0.272948757 0.757754057 4   50
2.31959 0.281255571 0.776337246 2   32
2.10626 0.426842961 0.778512783 4   46
2.0163  0.546051041 0.780669728 6   50
1.91282 0.433635614 0.809807372 2   48
1.67011 0.594238535 0.827360862 18  26
1.80076 0.719426666 0.830916931 4   26
2.29307 0.471266098 0.839754622 2   44
2.00811 0.574829217 0.839935299 2   40
2.25667 0.416338714 0.849465507 0   54
2.02098 0.306265093 0.860655587 4   42
2.10236 0.263078082 0.860656944 6   36
1.23721 0.236391255 0.879960428 6   44
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense:  you have different values of the variables at every location in a volume.  You won't get a surface from data like that.  You might want a series of surfaces, or a 3d contour plot (using `misc3d::contour3d`), but not a surface like the one you showed.  I can't show you any of this, because we don't have the `results` variable, so we can't run your code.  Can you put together a simple set of predictions?

Comment: Sorry for my question if it doesn't make sense. I'm a bit inexperienced with this and I'm still learning.
As I said above, I am trying to understand how forest cover, landscape heterogeneity and abundance of predators explain the probability of predation. I did model selection using other variables (e.g., richness of predators, period of the day) and the most parsimonious model is above. I'd like to represent this model in a single graph, if possible. Could I represent this model by the function you suggested? I'll update and put my dataset. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your predictions are a function of the three predictor variables, so you can't represent them as a single surface.  There are two common ways to do this:

1. Plot 3d contours using the `misc3d::contour3d` function.
2. Plot several surfaces for different values of one of the variables.

Before doing the first, some typos in your code need to be fixed:  sometimes you use `abun`, sometimes `abund`:  I'll always use `abun`.  You also have

```
gg$pred < -predict(model,newdata=gg, type = "response")
```

and the space in the middle of the `<-` changes the meaning completely.  Finally, using `dput(results)` makes the data easier for others to use.  Here's everything cleaned up:

```
results <- structure(list(het = c(1.90164, 2.13681, 2.18218, 2.10223, 2.11588, 
2.10288, 2.28891, 2.31959, 2.10626, 2.0163, 1.91282, 1.67011, 
1.80076, 2.29307, 2.00811, 2.25667, 2.02098, 2.10236, 1.23721
), cov = c(0.636460117, 0.409547496, 0.631526938, 0.568536934, 
0.390850929, 0.465843118, 0.272948757, 0.281255571, 0.426842961, 
0.546051041, 0.433635614, 0.594238535, 0.719426666, 0.471266098, 
0.574829217, 0.416338714, 0.306265093, 0.263078082, 0.236391255
), abun = c(0.730424235, 0.735686442, 0.744585387, 0.746072471, 
0.747720518, 0.754245798, 0.757754057, 0.776337246, 0.778512783, 
0.780669728, 0.809807372, 0.827360862, 0.830916931, 0.839754622, 
0.839935299, 0.849465507, 0.860655587, 0.860656944, 0.879960428
), pred = c(24L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 18L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 6L), npred = c(14L, 42L, 48L, 36L, 50L, 
42L, 50L, 32L, 46L, 50L, 48L, 26L, 26L, 44L, 40L, 54L, 42L, 36L, 
44L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))

model <- glm(cbind(pred,npred)~ cov + het + abun + abun:cov + cov:het,
             data=results, family=binomial)

het <- seq(0, 2, 0.05288)
cov <- seq(0, 0.8, 0.021600)
abun <- seq(0, 0.9, 0.024)
gg <- expand.grid(het=het, cov=cov, abun=abun)
gg$pred <- predict(model,newdata=gg, type = "response")
head(gg)
#       het cov abun         pred
# 1 0.00000   0    0 2.220446e-16
# 2 0.05288   0    0 2.220446e-16
# 3 0.10576   0    0 2.220446e-16
# 4 0.15864   0    0 2.220446e-16
# 5 0.21152   0    0 2.220446e-16
# 6 0.26440   0    0 2.220446e-16
```

To do a contour plot, you need to choose the contour levels.  You can see the range of predictions using

```
range(gg$pred)
# [1] 2.220446e-16 1.000000e+00
```

so your model predicts probabilities from essentially 0 to 1.  I'd like 20 contours between 0 and 1, but the `contour3d` function doesn't like out of range
contours, so I'll use 1/20, ..., 19/20:

```
levels <- (1:19)/20
colors <- heat.colors(19)
```

The `contour3d` function wants the values in an array, not a vector:

```
pred <- array(gg$pred, c(length(het), length(cov), length(abun)))
```

Now draw some axes, then the plot:

```
plot3d(gg, type = "n")
contour3d(pred, levels, het, cov, abun, color = colors, alpha = 0.5, add = TRUE)
```

The `alpha = 0.2` value makes the surfaces partially transparent; you might want to try other values between 0 and 1 to see what you like.  Here's what I got.  In R, you can rotate the plot to see it from different angles, or call `rglwidget()` to save it in a rotatable form that you can view on a web browser.

[image: screen shot]

I'll leave it to you to work out how to do the second kind of plot.

Comment: Thank you so much for the script and for the tips, I learned a lot from you. I have two more questions. Could you tell if I can add a legend like in the figure I showed? Is there some interaction with ggplot? Thank you

Comment: The `plot3Drgl` package does legends like that, but I don't think it does 3d contour plots.  (The `contour3Drgl` function does something else.)  I don't know if there's a way to mix the legends with other `rgl` code.